# Comic Book Identification - Sci-fi/Fantasy - Lost Soul Earthworm

Tags: story-identification, comics

When I was a kid(early 1990s), I read a graphic novel from the local library that I have been unable to find or identify.

Here are the clues:

- It's from the 1970s or 1980s, from what I remember of the art style.
- It felt like one of those strange sci-fi / fantasy mixes that were common in the 70s.
- It was black and white.
- The main character's soul becomes detached from his body and takes the form of a giant(human-sized) earthworm.
- The earthworm goes off and does its own thing. Our hero sometimes sees the earthworm in the distance, and at some point goes hunting for the thing, through forests and wastelands.
- The earthworm-soul thing was only ONE part of the comic's storyline. There was other stuff, but for the life of me, I can't
  remember what.

Comment: This is the same book that fjordfiesta is looking for [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/26767/looking-for-the-title-of-a-graphic-novel-featuring-a-spaceship-shaped-like-a-bir). I'm certain of it, I'm looking to find it too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had asked this same question almost five years ago, and just discovered that almost 9 months ago, [someone](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/70726/yatrik) (currently unregistered, so basically anonymous) was able to find the answer.
In case you also haven't been keeping up with this and need an update: the book is ["The Midnight Son", by Steven Miller](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/4302453-the-midnight-son). There are copies (in the US, anyway) available [`on Amazon`](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0590075829).

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure it is a comic book? Soul detachment and possession of other beings is also seen in a game called Monkey Brains. I used to play it back in the days of Windows 95.

Comment: Yeah, I'm quite sure it was a comic book / graphic novel. I'll check out that game, though! Haven't heard of it before.